# WCF Tcp binding in code issue

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp, binding

I've got a strange problem: I have a wcf service which needs to be hosted by tcp protocol on a standalone console application.

I have created a new console app project and added a lib reference for my wcf project. The problem occurs when I want to configure and broadcast the host.

```
var Uri = new Uri("net.tcp://myaddress:4322/MyService");
        MyServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ImyService), Uri);

        var binding = new NetTcpBinding();
        MyServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IImageExchangeService), binding, "");


        var mexBinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding();
        MyServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange),mexBinding, "");



        ServiceMetadataBehavior serviceBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        serviceBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        serviceBehavior.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
        MyServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceBehavior);
```

When it comes to open the host, I get this message:

> The contract name 'IMetadataExchange' could
>    not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service WcfService.Ser
>   vices.MyService.  Add a ServiceMetadataBehavior to the configuration
>   file or to the ServiceHost directly to enable support for this contract.

Comment: I would strongly recommend writing a good `app.config` file, where you have more control over binding and behaviors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I have better time to check this.

First you need to get the service behavior from the host or create a new one and add it if not found.

Setting the HttpGetEnabled requires you to also ad a metadata uri to the baseaddresses.

Also it does not seem to matter if the metadata endpoint is named "mex", as long as all endpoints added have unique names. So you can't use empty string for both endpoints.

```
var Uri = new Uri("net.tcp://myaddress:4322/MyService");
var MetadataUri = new Uri("http://myaddress:8000/MyService");
var MyServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), Uri, MetadataUri);

var serviceBehavior = MyServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
if (serviceBehavior == null)
{
    serviceBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    MyServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceBehavior);
}

serviceBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
serviceBehavior.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;

MyServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding(), "mex");

var binding = new NetTcpBinding();
MyServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IImageExchangeService), binding, "image");
```

Comment: There is no affect at all.